# Reacting to Workbook.BeforeSave event from an excel add-in

Tags: excel, excel-addins, vba

I want to run a validation VBA function on save of any workbook which uses my excel add-in when certain conditions are met, but my users are non technical so adding VBA code to each workbook's BeforeSave event to run the function is not an option.

Is it possible to attach a VBA function to the Workbook.BeforeSave event when the add-in loads?

Comment: you can create Application Event Handler in your addin to respond to events from any workbook.  [see here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx)

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!